# In Awesomium, CallJavascriptFunction can resolve the freeze state of javascript?

Tags: javascript, awesomium

I let two threads simultaneously invoke Javascript's functions, whose code's first statement is a alert statement showing the string "hello" & "world".

I expected that only when I click the alert with "hello", the alert "world" will show. But in fact the alert "world" dialog will cover the previous "hello" dialog.

and the code after the alert("hello") didn't execute at all. Why this happened?

```
private void OnJSCallback(object sender, JSCallbackEventArgs e)
{
    //Console.WriteLine("hi");
    MessageBox.Show("hi");

    if (count == 0)
    {
        Thread worker = new Thread(func =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
                OnReturn("CallFromNative1", "hello");
            });
        worker.Start();
    }

    if (count == 1)
    {
        Thread worker = new Thread(func =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            OnReturn("CallFromNative2", "world");
        });
        worker.Start();
    }
    count++;
}

private void OnReturn(string call, string ret)
{
    webControl.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((ThreadStart) delegate()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("before call javascript");
        webControl.CallJavascriptFunction("", call, new JSValue[] { new JSValue(ret)});
    });
}
```

And the JavaScript code is:

```
external.JSCallback("hello", "world");
external.JSCallback("wtf", "dude");
var count = 0;

function CallFromNative1()
{
alert(arguments[0]);
var i = 0;
count = 10;
alert(count);
for(i=0; i<1000; i++)
{
    count += i;
}
alert(count);
}

function CallFromNative2()
{
    alert(arguments[0]);
    alert(count);
}
```